# Arguments parsed by argparse are not accessible in other files

Tags: python, argparse

I have parsed arguments using `argparse` in my `main.py` files. I have a few variables defined in the `global_vars.py` file and this file is included in `main.py` and other files.

I am assigning parsed arguments to global variables, but when I try to access these global variables across files other than `main.py` it returns `None`. Is there anything that I am missing, or is it a namespace problem for `argparse`?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Accept arguments')
    parser.add_argument('-n', help='enter period for which you want to do the sampling')
    parser.add_argument('-b', help='enter directory for bhav copy')
    parser.add_argument('-d', help='enter directory for deliverables')
    parser.add_argument('-l', help='enter list type')

    args = parser.parse_args(namespace=None)
    var_dict = vars(args)
    bhavcopy_dir=var_dict['b']
    deli_dir=var_dict['d']
    no_of_sessions=var_dict['n']
    list_type=var_dict['l']
```

Comment: Rather than trying to use global state, why not call some entry point function with the appropriate arguments? Could you show some more of the context this is in?

Comment: You need to also show us how you are trying to access these variables from other files. Perhaps the other files are being run before your argument parsing has happened.

Comment: `bhavcopy_dir = args.b` works without the `vars_dict` conversion. (not that this changes you bigger question)

Answer (score 0):

Note that any code you put inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` will only run if you run the python file directly. So if that code is suppose to be your global_var.py, and you are simply importing global_var, then that code is not running and your variables are never initialised. Put some print statements in to verify if/when your variables are actually being created.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` isn't the only thing that has a namespace.  Every module (file) and function has one.  `argparse` just returns an object of class `argparse.Namespace`, which can be treated like the namespace of a module.  That is, you access items in that object with the `args.name` syntax.

Once you've done something like

```
bhavcopy_dir = args.b
```

`bhavcopy_dir` is an argument in the `main` namespace.  You can access it by that name elsewhere in `main`.  But if `main` is imported, access changes.

We need to see more of `main.py`. I suspect it includes

```
import argparse
import global_vars
# or is it
# from global_vars import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     ....
     args = ...
     var1 = args.var1
```

With `import global_vars`, you access variables defined there with `global_vars.var1`.  With the `*` import, `var1` loaded in to the global (**main**) namespace.

`import argparse` loads the `argparse` namespace.  `argparse.ArgumentParser` is accessing an object (class) within that module.

Do I also need to explain how that `if __name__...` block changes importation?

Your question is about modules, namespaces and imports, not so much about `argparse`.

As suggested in the comments, it is often handy to just pass the `args` variable around, and access its attributes as needed.

Maybe this pair of files will illustrate the issues (without argparse)

`main1.py` file:

```
import sub1
print(sub1.var1)
var_from_main = 123
sub1.foo(var_from_main)
sub1.test()
```

`sub1.py` file:

```
var1 = 345
def test():
    print(var_from_main) 
def foo(var):
    print(var)  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    var1 = 'sub __main__ setting'
```

`var1` defined in `sub1` is accessible from `main1` (with the right name), but value set in the `__name__` block is not used by the import.

The variable set in `main1`, is not accessible in imported module.

```
1021:~/mypy$ python3 main1.py
345
123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main1.py", line 5, in <module>
    sub1.test()
  File "/home/paul/mypy/sub1.py", line 3, in test
    print(var_from_main) 
NameError: name 'var_from_main' is not defined
```